# OHAttributedlabel truncated last line of a multiline label

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm using `OHAttributed` label. I want that if the label is longer that 3 lines, that the third line ends with `"..."`.

First of all, I calculated the height of the frame of my `OHAttributedlabel` like this.

```
    OHAttributedLabel *lblAppointment = [[OHAttributedLabel alloc]init];      
    lblAppointment.numberOfLines = 0;
    lblAppointment.attributedText = atrAppointment;
    [atrAppointment setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:13]];
    appointmentRect.size.height = [self heightForLabel:atrAppointment];
    lblHeight += appointmentRect.size.height + 5;
    [lblAppointment setFrame:appointmentRect];
    [self addSubview:lblAppointment];
```

Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: Have set `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` ?

Comment: When I set that, it only shows the first line and then truncates it's tail

Answer (score 0):

Try With set Line Break mode to `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`,

Check this

```
OHAttributedLabel *lblAppointment = [[OHAttributedLabel alloc]init];      
lblAppointment.numberOfLines = 3;
lblAppointment.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
lblAppointment.attributedText = atrAppointment;
[atrAppointment setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:13]];
appointmentRect.size.height = [self heightForLabel:atrAppointment];
lblHeight += appointmentRect.size.height + 5;
[lblAppointment setFrame:appointmentRect];
[self addSubview:lblAppointment];
```

Comment: Have you set `numberOfLines`=3; ?

Comment: Yes i dit set it to 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `OHATTributedLabel`, you can draw the string using string Drawing option `NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine` and `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin`.These drawing options give you exactly what you want.